# How to send mms in Android 6.0

Tags: android, mms

I try to send MMS in my application，but status.getStatusCode() return 500。There is very little information. Is there a similar procedure?Here is my sample code.

```
final String mmscUrl = "http://mmsc.vnet.mobi";
    String subject="test";
    String recipient="187******";
    SendReq sendReq=new SendReq();
    EncodedStringValue[] sub=EncodedStringValue.extract(subject);
    if (sub!=null && sub.length>0){
        sendReq.setSubject(sub[0]);
    }
    EncodedStringValue []phoneNumbers=EncodedStringValue.extract(recipient);
    if (phoneNumbers!=null && phoneNumbers.length>0){
        sendReq.addTo(phoneNumbers[0]);
    }

    PduBody pduBody = new PduBody();
    PduPart part = new PduPart();
    part.setName("sample".getBytes());
    part.setContentType("image/png".getBytes());
    PduPart partPdu = new PduPart();
    partPdu.setCharset(CharacterSets.UTF_8);
    partPdu.setName(part.getName());
    partPdu.setContentType(part.getContentType());
    String furl= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/01.jpg";
    //Log.e("111",furl);
    File file=new File(furl);
    Uri pngUri=Uri.fromFile(file);
    partPdu.setDataUri(pngUri);
    pduBody.addPart(partPdu);
    sendReq.setBody(pduBody);
    PduComposer composer=new PduComposer(context,sendReq);
    final byte []bytesToSend=composer.make();
    //Log.e("111",new String(bytesToSend));
    byte[] s=HttpUtils.httpConnection(context,4444L,mmscUrl,bytesToSend,HttpUtils.HTTP_POST_METHOD,true,"10.0.0.200", 80);
```

here's my Log.

```
01-17 16:26:53.652 17872-21013/com.example.mmssendmessage E/Mms:HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error:system failure.
01-17 16:26:53.652 17872-21013/com.example.mmssendmessage E/Mms: Url: 
  http://mmsc.vnet.mobi
  HTTP error: Internal Server Error:system failure.
```

Operators are able to receive MMS based on some information.
I can now receive MMS and download them, but sending MMS will not succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "There is very little information." Is not very precise. Could you add the stack trace of the error and mayb check if your provider actually supports MMS?

Comment: ** 01-17 16：26：53.652 17872-21013 / com.example.mmssendmessage E / Mms：HTTP / 1.1 500内部服务器错误：系统故障。01-17 16：26：53.652 17872-21013 / com.example.mmssendmessage E / Mms：Url：http://mmsc.vnet.mobi HTTP错误：内部服务器错误：系统故障。

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48296278/edit) that into the question, rather than post as a comment

Comment: The operator's address is based on the information I have found. Now I can receive MMS and download them, but the delivery cannot be successful.

Comment: a HTTP 500 error means the server doesnt like what you're POST'ing to it - or what you're posting is causing it to crash - like supplying an empty value to a .Net web application thats not properly coded would cause it to throw a object reference not set to instance of object exception with a 500 error.  There's no other information being returned like a stack trace from the server?

Comment: @JGlass Yes, I only get so much information back.